# An extra line appears on the leftmost point of additional display. How do I fix it?

Tags: ati, graphics, display

I have a screen which I attach to my laptop. When I use the "Extend" mode, one column of pixels at the right end of the left display screen creeps up to the leftmost part of my right display. Its really annoying, particularly when I am watching movies etc. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and do:

```
$ xrandr -q
```

This will return some information about how your displays are configured, you will get something like this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3285 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  

VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       60.0
```

In this case, eDP is the first monitor and HDMI-0 is secondary. Make note of the width in pixels for the primary screen and the id of the secondary display to be able to issue the following command:

```
$ xrandr --output <sec_screen_id> --pos <primary_display_width - few pixels>x0
```

for example:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos  1364x0
```

Play with different values until you are happy with the results and then include it on a startup script (probably on ~/.xprofile).